# Android Fragment method most appropriate for initializing/loading data

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have some data to load in an Android Fragment. I need to make a network connection. I am wondering what is the most appropriate method to start loading data. Should it be

```
onCreateView()
```

or

```
onStart()
```

or

```
onResume()
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

IMO `onCreate()` is the most appropriate selection. Because this callback is not included in the lifecycle if the Fragment goes to the background and comes to the foreground again. It will only be called if the Fragment is created.

In onCreateView and any following callback you have to determine when you wanna call the network. This will disappear if you choose onCreate().

If the context is needed, onAttach() is the better choice. Because onAttach() will get the Activity as a parameter and is like onCreate() independent of the foreground/background lifecycle.

Comment: But you have to make sure that when the network responds your views are != null. Views are accessible after onViewCreated() is called.

Comment: @DavidCorsalini this was my reasoning for not going with onCreate()

Comment: And if you need Context (or Activity) instance to instantiate Loader, for example, you should place this piece of code in onActivityCreated().

Comment: @DavidCorsalini Call the network in onCreate() and display the data after the Views are ready. For this you have to hold the data somewhere. I suggest this here because I don't know what's the size of the data loaded from the network will be. If it's huge onCreateView() isn't the right choice.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do that in `onResume()`. I then just use a `boolean` to know if I have to fetch data:

```
if (!dataFetched) {
    fetchData();
    dataFetched = true;
}
```

You could anticipate it, but you'll need to check if your views are accessible. If they're not, you have to keep the data and use it in `onViewCreated()`:

```
onCreate() {   // or onActivityCreated() if you need Context
    fetchData();
}

onViewCreated() {
    if (data != null) {
        loadDataInViews();
    }
}

onNetworkResponseArrived(Data response) { // Method called by the network callback
    if(views != null) {
        loadDataInViews();
    }
    else {
        data = response;
    }
}
```